# deep linking, page reloads, angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have a table which should be filtered depending on the url.

This is my module::

```
angular.module('myApp', ['pipelibservice']).
    config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/pipes/:pipeID', {templateUrl: 'partials/wizard.html',   controller: PipeListCtrl});
    }]);
```

In my template I have a list with a href that should filter the table:

```
    <li ng-repeat="pipe in pipes">
        <a href='#/pipes/{{ pipe.code }}'>{{ pipe.code }} - {{pipe.title_en}}</a>
    </li>
```

This is my index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Google Phone Gallery</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/app.css" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-strap/0.7.2/angular-strap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular/angular-resource.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-view></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Problem is, the entire page reloads when I hit the link. I only want the url to change so my table is filtered. How do I fix so the page is not reloaded?

**Update:**
I've narrowed it down to the rest API call. If i replace the rest call with hardcoded values (from the orginal rest-call) then it works. Any idea what can be wrong?

Comment: Have you tried with [ng-href](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_KITQCROC5uo/TQ_2NaQ7ENI/AAAAAAAAAU0/NKPMlHG8OGY/s1600/gatos-04.jpg) instead of href?

Comment: This is actually dependent on the interaction of the route with ng-view, how is your view structure setup. Do you have a fiddle of this problem occurring?

Comment: Sorry, have no fiddle. I added my index.html in my question.

Comment: When you say entire page, do you mean a full browser refresh (i.e. download all the scripts and such again) or just a route change (i.e. loading the new page via ajax and js)?

The point of routes is to change page via javascript, although without a real browser reload, not to just change the url.

Answer (score 2):

you cant normally use $route and not refresh the page. but in your case i would just use a filter http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:filter

```
<li ng-repeat="pipe in pipes | filter: pipeID">
    <a href='#/pipes/{{ pipe.code }}'>{{ pipe.code }} - {{pipe.title_en}}</a>
</li>
```

dont forget to put in ctrl $scope.pipeID = $routeParams.pipeID

P.S. i wrote a post explaning a bit simpler Ben Nadels idea (which is awesome) and its a way to use $route without refreshing http://bresleveloper.blogspot.co.il/2013/08/breslevelopers-angularjs-tutorial-basic_20.html

the point is that using $route with templateUrl and/or controller creates new instances of the controller and view, and by ur description u dont want it. so u can drop the templateUrl controller and send a custom parameter and in the app use ngSwitch to switch ngInclude and u manage it all with 1 controller

Answer (score 1):

As per [ngHref documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angHref), you should use `ng-click` to prevent the page reload:

```
<a href='' ng-click="goToPipe({{pipe.code}})">{{ pipe.code }} - {{pipe.title_en}}</a>
```

You would need to create the `goToPipe` function in your controller, with something like:

```
$scope.goToPipe = function (pipe_code) {
    $location.path("/pipe/" + pipe_code);
};
```

Comment: It still reloads the page. Tried all diffrent combos at docs.

Comment: When I move the content from wizard.html to index.html (skipping routing) then it works. So it has something to do with the routing.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I've found to this problem so far is this:
http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2441-Nested-Views-Routing-And-Deep-Linking-With-AngularJS.htm

Take a look at their demo:
http://bennadel.github.io/AngularJS-Routing/#/pets/cats/10/medical-history
Notice the tabs BACKGROUND, DIET, MEDICAL HISTORY and how the do not refresh the page.

However this solution is very complex and involves and employing a lot of non-native to angular stuff.

I'm still looking to find a simpler solution to this simple problem.